# How to fetch mongodb result in graphql

Tags: mongodb, graphql

```
const axios = require('axios');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/graphql";

const {
GraphQLObjectType,
GraphQLInt,
GraphQLString,
GraphQLBoolean,
GraphQLList,
GraphQLSchema
} = require('graphql');

// Launch Type
const LaunchType = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'Launch',
fields: () => ({
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
})
});

// Root Query
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        launches: {
        type: new GraphQLList(LaunchType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
                    client.db('graphql').collection('users').find()
                });
            }
        },
    }
});
module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
query: RootQuery
});
```

here i am trying to connect graphql - express - mongodb

but i think some issue with my RootQuery i am getting error with res.

I am new to it and don't know how to fetch data and return

please help me connect it properly. please have a look.

Comment: Add the error you get in your question. So, it will be easy to understand .

Comment: Not getting any errors. Getting launches as null

Answer (score 0):

here how you connect express-graphql

```
const express = require('express');
const expressGraphQL = require('express-graphql');
const schema = require('./schema');

const app = express();


app.use(
   '/graphql',
   expressGraphQL({
     schema,
     graphiql: true
    })
);
```

you return the connection in the resolve correct it to

```
 resolve(parent, args) {
         MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
             return  client.db('graphql').collection('users').find()
         });
 }
```

Comment: getting null respponse

Comment: check the connection on the browser first if it is ok http://localhost:3000/graphql

Comment: if you are not using 3000 as a port replace your port

Comment: what the problem with 5000 port?

Comment: same issue. null result

Comment: in the Browser can you see your queries schema at the right side?

Comment: no url : http://localhost:3000/graphql?query=%7B%0A%20%20launches%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198007/discussion-between-nemer-and-soubhagya-pradhan).

Answer (score 0):

You can return promises that return the value from the resolver. In your case you're returning a callback function and you're not returning the inner promise.

Also here you're connecting to the database in your resolver so you will be connecting/disconnecting from the database on every request to your API which is not a good practice. its better to connect once and reuse the connection

```
const client = await MongoClient.connect(url)
// Root Query
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        launches: {
        type: new GraphQLList(LaunchType),
            resolve(parent, args) {
                return client.db('graphql').collection('users').find()
                });
            }
        },
    }
});
module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
query: RootQuery
});
```